# Counting elements inside a matrix

Tags: r

I'm generating random matrices filled with zero and ones. The dimension of them might be different for each simulation.

An example matrix below

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
 [4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
 [6,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    1     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1     1
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
```

And a little visualisation

[image]

Dput version.

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))
```

I would like to compute two things:

1. the number of clusters formed by ones (by cluster we mean a set of adjacent ones, where the elements on the diagonal are not adjacent),
2. the number of ones within each cluster.

I think I managed to solve the first point with this function

```
library(raster)
count_clusters <- function(grid) {
  attr(clump(raster(grid), direc=4), 'data')@max
}
```

This function would return 14 for the matrix above which is correct.

Unfortunately I don't how to solve the second task. The needed function should return the following output: `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5)`.

I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: In generall it is a good praxis to share example data with `dput` so ppl can easily copy-paste it. Or include code that generates the example data.

Comment: @Baraliuh, of course. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the number of ones within each cluster:

```
grid <-structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
                                                                                         10L))                                                                                                +                                                                                   10L))
x <- clump(raster(grid), direc=4)
```

get the values from the RasterLayer @data@values.

```
vals <- x@data@values
```

Create a data frame with the values:

```
dt <- tibble(cluster = vals)
```

Remove NA values, group by cluster and count

```
result <- dt %>% 
  filter(!is.na(cluster)) %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  tally()

result$n
 [1] 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 2 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!